# How to exclude devices with legacy camera hardware level in manifest?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-manifest, android-camera2

I need my app to be available only for devices which has the next camera hardware level:

```
 CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED
 CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL
 CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_3
 CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_EXTERNAL
```

So for `CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY` it should not be available

How I can do it?

In manifest I specify that app only available for devices which has camera:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Now I need to add also hardware levels somehow, and it should be one of them, OR condition

On https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#hw-features I found only

[image]

But If a device doesn't have FULL level camera then will it be excluded? In this case app won't be available for Limited, 3, or External cameras.